# How to intercept a Ping message from the Openfire Server?

Tags: java, plugins, xmpp, openfire

I am writing an Openfire plugin to intercept the Ping message the server sends to the client when the client becomes idle. The system Ping looks like:

```
<iq from='capulet.lit' to='juliet@capulet.lit/balcony' id='s2c1' type='get'>
  <ping xmlns='urn:xmpp:ping'/>
</iq>
```

However, when I use a PacketInterceptor to intercept all the packets between the server and the clients, the interceptor is able to intercept all the packets EXCEPT for the Ping. I don't understand what is going on. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you able to catch the presence packets?

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a simplest example of packet interceptor that logs every incoming and outgoing packet.
http://faisalbhagat.blogspot.com/2014/03/openfire-logging-using-packetinterceptor.html

Answer (score 0):

Below is the override method `intercepPacket` in my plugin, it could intercept the ping message. 
For your reference ~ :)

```
@Override
public void interceptPacket(org.xmpp.packet.Packet packet, Session session,
        boolean incoming, boolean processed) throws PacketRejectedException {
    if (incoming && !processed) {
        String packetXml = packet.toXML();
        logger.warn("\n" + new XmlFormatter().format(packetXml));
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand that you have used incoming in the if statement because you want to process an incoming message to the server from the client but what is the meaning of using !processed? @BrownyLin