# How to Intercept StartTLS from Openfire

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire, starttls

I am writin an Openfire Plugin and I need to intercept the StartTLS request and all the TLS handshake between the Client and the Server.
I read some topics with the interface PacketInterceptor for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16879098/14379956

I can log all packets but I don't see the TLS's ones.

Does someone has an idea of how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with Openfire's PacketInterceptor API. That API is designed to intercept common XMPP stanzas that are exchanged after a session has been established, not the data that is used to establish such a session.